# HTMl direct rtl issue-arabic

Tags: html

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <label class="control-label">Region</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="searchdata" class="form-control" dir="rtl" alpha-numeric-space  />  
</div>
```

I am implementing Arabic input in the text box. Currently the above is code is working from **right to left**. But the solution what I need is When a user gives white space or comma, it should come towards the left side, but the above code will take towards the right side. I browsed through so many sites, but I didn't get the appropriate answer. 
Any help/advice greatly appreciated.

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/YIrUrep4q5dUnmh8usrz

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Instead of using `dir="rtl"`, use `style="direction:rtl;"`.
Inputs don't behave like normal tags witch contain text (, mainly because the text isn't stored in the tag content), and this may solve your problem.

Comment: I tried your logic. But it didn't solve my issue. Still, I am facing the same old problem

Comment: What browser are you using, btw?

Comment: Chrome 65 browser

Comment: Ok then, I don't know what's happening, and I can't check your Plunker right now. Keep searching :D